# Объединение строк за скобками

Tags: python

Пытаюсь решить задачку:

> A backslash is used to escape a quote so it can be used in strings
> such as 'It's me' and "She said "Hello"". The special symbol '\n'
> is used to add a line break to a string.  Print out this text using
> one string: The name of this ice-cream is "Sweeet'n'Tasty"

Исходник:

```
dont_worry = "Don't worry about apostrophes"
print(dont_worry)
print("The name of this ice-cream is \"Sweeet\"")
print('text')
```

Мое решение неправильное:

```
dont_worry = "Don't worry about apostrophes"
print(dont_worry)
print("The name of this ice-cream is \"Sweeet\'n\'Tasty\"")
print('Tasty')
```

Как объединить две строки?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы заэкранировать все кавычки, используя обратный слэш (`\`) на Питоне:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# входная строчка с новыми строками и кавычками
input_string = '''The name of this
ice-cream is "Sweeet'n'Tasty"'''
# выводим строку, подходящую для использования как строковая константа в Питоне
print(repr(input_string))
# -> 'The name of this\nice-cream is "Sweeet\'n\'Tasty"'
```

Новая строка превратилась в `\n`, и одинарные кавычки заэскейплены. В Питоне нужно эскейпить только внешние кавычки, поэтому двойные кавычки остались как есть.

Если хочется заэкранировать все кавычки, новые строки, то можно использовать регулярные выражения:

```
import re

s = re.sub(r'''('|")''', r'\\\1', input_string) # заменяем кавычки
print(re.sub(r'\n', r'\\n', s)) # заменяем новые строки
# -> The name of this\nice-cream is \"Sweeet\'n\'Tasty\"
```

Если не нужно поддерживать более сложные преобразования, то можно использовать str.replace метод:

```
s = input_string
for c in '\'"':
    s = s.replace(c, '\\' + c)
print(s.replace('\n', '\\n'))
```

Этот код выводит тот же результат.

**Обновление**

[[@chemtech](/users/24663/chemtech)](/users/24663/chemtech) мой ответ показывает, как можно сгенерировать строковую константу для решения задачи, описанной в вопросе: *Print out this text using one string: `The name of this ice-cream is "Sweeet'n'Tasty"`* (новая строка добавлена для полноты и проверки понимания). Картинка же просто просит заменить `"'"` (внешние двойные кавычки) на `'\''` (на одинарные) прямо в исходном коде. Просто следуй инструкции.

Comment: Спасибо за решение. Но, похоже, в программе нужно писать что-то другое.
http://habrastorage.org/files/4be/a7c/5fa/4bea7c5fa9f34f3a9ba0fdf4488bc4a5.png

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Тоже столкнулся с этой проблемой. В который раз перечитывал "can be used in strings such as 'It\'s me' and "She said \"Hello\"" и решил, что в print ' ' нужно эскейпить только одинарные скобки, а в print " " - двойные. Попробовал - и действительно.

Answer (score 0):

Я не люблю когда то, что должно работать, не работает :) В итоге, залез в документы и нашел там проекты PyCharm ;) Открыл упражнение 3 8-ю задачу. Открыл файл с тестами. Подсмотрел ответ. Проблема была возможно из-за того, что нужно было перезагрузить модуль

```
from test_helper import run_common_tests, get_answer_placeholders, passed, failed

def test_value():
    window = get_answer_placeholders()[0]
    print(window)
    first = "The name of this ice-cream is \\\"Sweeet'n'Tasty\\\""
    second = 'The name of this ice-cream is "Sweeet\\\'n\\\'Tasty"'

    if first in window or second in window:
        passed()
    else:
        failed("Sorry, the wrong string is printed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_common_tests()
    test_value()
```

Вывел window. Подставил в ответ один из правильных вариантов.
Резюме: Лучше книжки умные читать.
Например, М.Лутц

Answer (score 0):

*Нехорошие люди* придумали это задание! Я час потратил на него! Мой ответ такой:

```
dont_worry = "Don't worry about apostrophes"
print(dont_worry)
print("The name of this ice-cream is \"Sweeet\"")
print('The name of this ice-cream is "Sweeet\'n\'Tasty"')
```